# What is quantile normalization?

Tags: normalization, quantiles

Is anyone familiar with quantile normalization? As I understand it's a way to "polish" a set of datasets so that they have the same "statistical properties" (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_normalization))? I wonder if anyone knows what are the statistical properties that they refer to when they say

> quantile normalization is a technique for making two distributions identical in statistical properties.

Are those statistical properties the mean, median, or standard deviation?

Comment: Of possible interest (although it focus on genetics): [How does quantile normalization work?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10744/930)

Comment: The Wikipedia description sounds an awful lot like a sample-based version of the [Probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) between two continuous distributions.