# Limit of quantile normalization

Tags: normalization, bioinformatics, microarray

Is [quantile normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10744/how-does-quantile-normalization-work) adequate for normalizing
data with very few samples?

For example this microarray data. Typically after normalization 
we'd like to compare `Cancer-1 with Normal` and `Cancer-2 with Normal`
for differential expression.

```
    mRNA     Cancer-Type-1   Cancer-Type-2  Normal
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    mRNA1      30        49    12
    mRNA2     199        200   78
    ...        ...       ...  ....
    mRNA1000   13        40    88
```

If not what is the appropriate normalization method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantile normalization works well when the samples are comparable (ie have a high correlation). We don't know whether that is the case with your data.  There is nothing in the algorithm that requires a large number of arrays, but realistically with only 3 arrays your analysis is pretty limited no matter what the normalization method.

Comment: Thanks. Why "high correlation" is needed? Any reference for that?